# create a countdown that the remain time is equal no mather the country

Tags: javascript, datetime, countdown, countdowntimer

i can image someone had donde this already or it can be considered a duplicated question, i've been searching for weeks and i can't figure out how to accomplish this.

I have a countdown made in js, the problem i'm facing is that when ever i test it in another country the times throw out different hours example.

i'm in centralamerica, end date is  apr 16, 2018 23:59:59" if i test this in centralamerica it says 6 days and 10 hours remaining, if i run this in italy for example it says 6 days and 3 hours remaining, i need it to be equal all the time and that the timezone doesn´t affects, is this even possible, and please help on how to get it done.

the script i have is working but not the way i need to, i have a promo that will expire on "apr 16, 2018 23:59:59" so if it only has 5 hours remaining it shout say 5 hours remaining no matter where its been seeing from, but that is not happening.

```
$("#masterslider").append("<p id='demo'>.</p>")
  $("#masterslider").append("<span> remaining time  </span>")

//******************************** update date here ************************
var serverDate = new Date("apr 16, 2018 23:59:59");
var offset = serverDate.getTimezoneOffset();
serverDate = addOffset(serverDate, offset);

 setInterval(function(){
    updateCountdown();
}, 1000);

 function addOffset(date, offset) {
    var time = date.getTime() ;
 return new Date(time + offset  * 6000);
}

 function updateCountdown() {
 var userDate = new Date();

    var distance = serverDate.getTime() - userDate.getTime();

    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
   //var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


  if(serverDate.getTime()  > userDate.getTime()){

       $('#demo').html( days +"day(s)"+ " / " + hours + "hour(s)"  + minutes + "minutes(s)");

  }
   else 
  {
   $("#demo").html(mas); 
   $("#masterslider span").hide();
 }


 }
 </script>
```

Comment: _I have a promo that will expire on "apr 16, 2018 23:59:59"_- of which timezone?

Comment: i need it to be based on UTC+2 since this is hosted in spain, but will be seen in centra lamerica and the caribbean

Comment: just specify timezone in referent time value `new Date("apr 16, 2018 23:59:59 GMT-0600")`

Comment: it did not worked, it kept the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked and setting correct timezone for "event timestamp" works for me regardless local client timezone I use.

```js
let targetDate = new Date("2018-04-11 23:59:59 GMT-0800");
let refreshDelayMs = 1000;
function updateCounter() {
   let distance = (targetDate - new Date()) / 1000;
   let seconds = Math.floor(distance % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
   distance = distance / 60;
   let minutes = Math.floor(distance % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
   distance = distance / 60;
   let hours = Math.floor(distance % 24).toString().padStart(2, '0');
   let days = Math.floor(distance / 24).toString().padStart(2, '0');
   document.querySelector('.counter').innerHTML = `${days} days ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
   setTimeout(updateCounter, refreshDelayMs);
}

updateCounter();
```

```html
Remains: <span class="counter"></span>
```

Comment: it worked perfect for me, is there somewhere i can read about this to understand it completely and learn more?

Comment: if you don't specify timezone in timestamp it means local user timezone. And this *is not* your case. That's all :)

Comment: i ran this code in firefox mozilla and i got Remains: NaN days NaN:NaN:NaN

Comment: yes, and `new Date("2018-04-11 23:59:59 GMT-0800")` returns `Invalid date`. Definitely Firefox expects another date format used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment-timezone from [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment-timezone) or use [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timezone)

[repl.it sample](https://repl.it/@tejzpr/JealousDenseDifferences)

```js
const moment = require("moment-timezone");

function toTimeZone(time, offset) {
    var format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';
    return moment(time, format).utcOffset(offset).format(format);
}

toTimeZone("2018/04/10 15:37", "+0730")
```